# Orbit under monoid action in GAP

Tags: monoid, gap

I have a monoid in GAP, defined by five transformations, and I wish to find the orbit of an element (say, 1) under the action of this monoid.

I found the this [source](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean.michel/gap3/htm/chap079.htm#SECT002), which indicates I should be able to just type `Orbit(M,1);` to find what I want, but I get an error message:

```
Error, no 1st choice method found for `PreOrbishProcessing' on 1 arguments called from
PreOrbishProcessing( G ) at /proc/cygdrive/C/gap4r8/lib/oprt.gd:826 called from
<function "Orbit">( <arguments> )
```

The top of that page says the functions are contained in the file action.g, which I don't seem to have and cannot find online. Any help on how to obtain the functions in action.g or how to achieve my goal using other GAP functions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to a GAP3 manual but are using GAP4. My understanding is that in GAP4 this functionality has migrated into the `Semigroups` package,
https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/semigroups.html

Comment: I have also looked at documentation for the Semigroups package, but I haven't been able to figure out how to compute the orbit of an element. The section on orbits references the Orb package, and the link to documentation on that leads to a page that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I'm not a semigroups specialist but this package is the newer version of the GAP3 package that provided this orbit functionality. I'd suggest you write to the package authors and ask about this.